# Selecting the text from a div and including it into a email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have a email sender on a website, people can complete the required input boxes and than press send and i receive a email. The text from all the input boxes are added in the email body text. The website also has a way to generate some texts in some div with the class="tag" (the divs look like some kind of tags). How can i add the text from all the divs with the class tag into the email? This is the code i use:

JS

```
$(function() {

$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');


                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                $('.tag').remove();



            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later or send a email at order@o-p-a-l.eu");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
empty($_POST['email'])      ||
empty($_POST['phone'])      ||
empty($_POST['message'])        ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$products = $_POST['products'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'order@order.eu'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail:    $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message\n\nProduct ordered: $products";
$headers = "From: order@order.eu\n"; // This is the email address the   generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

HTML

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>


<div class="cart" contenteditable="false">

<div class="tag">01A001-Z03-71021<span class="remove">X</span></div>
<div class="tag">02A001-Z03-71021<span class="remove">X</span></div>
<div class="tag">03A001-Z03-71021<span class="remove">X</span></div>

<input type="text" class="newtag" placeholder="Your items" id="" readonly />
</div>

<button id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to include the content in the email body, or how to style the text in the email body?

Comment: To include the content of the div (only the text, 01A001-Z03-71021, 02A001-Z03-71021 and 03A001-Z03-71021 in this case) in the email body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do something like this you can use the `getElementsByClassName` function

```
// find all elements with the 'tag' class
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('tag');
var tagText = '';

// loop through each found element and get the innerText property
for (var i=0; i< tags.length; i++){
    tagText += tags[i].innerText + ' ';
}

// trim the trailing whitespace
tagText = tagText.trim();
```

You'd now want to add `tagText` to your `message` variable

---

**Edit**

I've just noticed the child node in the `tag` div. I guess this is the real question: how do you get the `tag` text without including the `remove` text?

You can use the `childNodes` property of the element

```
// get all the elements as before:
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('tag');
var tagText = '';

// loop through each found element and use the childNodes property
for (var i=0; i< tags.length; i++){
    tagText += tags[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ' ';
}

// trim the trailing whitespace
tagText = tagText.trim();
```

Note that `childNodes` do not return text. They are objects, so to get the value the `nodeValue` property must be used.

Here's a link to MDN: [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

---

**Including this Code into Yours**

You need to add this code to your `SubmitSuccess` method:

```
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
    // get values from FORM
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();

    // this is where you're getting your message text
    var message = $("textarea#message").val();

    // add in the childNodes code
    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('tag');
    var tagText = '';
    for (var i=0; i< tags.length; i++){
        tagText += tags[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ' ';
    }
    // trim the trailing whitespace
    tagText = tagText.trim();

    // add the message body and the tag text together:
    message = message + 'Tags: ' + tagText;

    // continue your code as before
    ....
```

Comment: Sorry, exactly how do i use this code? I am new at JS.